# from affine matroid to measures

Tags: matroid-theory, measure-theory, simplicial-volume, linear-algebra, combinatorial-geometry

Let $S$ be an arbitrary finite spanning subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ of cardinality $N$. Let
$W(S)$ be the formal $\mathbb{R}$-vector space generated by all $d$-dimensional
simplices (i.e. bases of the affine matroid $\mathcal{M}(S)$ of $S$) with vertices in $S$. In particular

$\dim W(S) =$ number of simplices= number of bases of $\mathcal{M}(S)$.

For a given simplex $\Delta$ with vertices from $S$ define the volume form
$w_\Delta=\chi_\Delta d Vol$, where $\chi_\Delta$ is the characteristic
function of $\Delta$.  Let $V(S)$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-linear span of $w_\Delta$
where $\Delta$ runs over all simplices with vertices in $S$.  We have a natural
projection $\Pi: W(S)\to V(S).$   Let $K(S)$ be the kernel of $\Pi.$ Our main
goal is to describe this kernel.

First we describe some obvious elements from
$W(S)$ lying in $K(S)$. Take an arbitrary $(d+2)$-tuple $T$ of points from $S$
spanning $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Then there exists a standard element of
$K(S)$ associated to $T$. Namely, there exist exactly two triangulations of the
convex hull of $T$ by the simplices with vertices in $T$.  Considering the
difference of these triangulations as an element of $W(S)$ we get the required
element of $K(S)$.  For example, there are two "different"  types of spanning 4-tuples
of points in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Case 1 with the convex hull which is a 4-gon and
Case 2 with the convex hull which is a triangle. In Case 1 we have a relation
that the sum of 2 triangles = the sum of two other triangles. Thus we have an
element of $K(S)$ of the form $\Delta_1+\Delta_2-\Delta_3-\Delta_4$ In Case 2
we have that the biggest triangle $\Delta_1$ equals either the sum of 3 smaller triangles 
(and so we have an element of $K(S)$ of the form $\Delta_1-\Delta_2-\Delta_3-\Delta_4$)
or $\Delta_1$, with one side having 3 points from $S$, equals the sum of 2 smaller triangles 
(and so we have an element of $K(S)$ of the form $\Delta_1-\Delta_2-\Delta_3$)

**Conjecture**. $K(S)$ is spanned by the above standard kernel elements
coming from spanning $(d+2)$-tuples of points from $S$.

We are able to show that Conjecture holds for $S$ for which any
$(d+2)$-subset of points is spanning.

This statement sounds to us as an exercise(?) from matroid theory. In particular, we are
sure that $\dim K(S)$ is an invariant of $\mathcal{M}(S)$.

Can you recognize Conjecture as a known statement from
matroid theory (or, even, a version of de Rham's Theorem)?

Comment: Are you aware of the corresponding papers "Fiber polytopes" by Billera and Sturmfels, and "The polytope of all triangulations of a point configuration" by de Loera, Hosten, Santos and Sturmfels?
Perhaps also "Exterior algebras and projections of polytopes" by Filliman might be useful.


Comment: We certainly are aware of the construction fiber polytopes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This conjecture is proven in theorem 7.4 of ["Incidence matrices, geometrical bases, combinatorial prebases and matroids"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X97001076) by T.V. Alekseyevskaya and I.M. Gelfand ($n=2$) and theorem 4.5 in ["Bases in Systems of Simplices and Chambers"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9707218) by Alekseyevskaya for higher $n$.

A previous version of this answer described the similar situation with scissor congruence groups, but I'm no longer certain that one can get a proof using such theorems anymore. It is worth mentioning here that there is a very similar [theorem of Pachner](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35061/a-pachner-complex-for-triangulated-manifolds) which says that two PL-homeomorphic triangulated PL-manifolds are related by a sequence of "bistellar flips", which are essentially the generating relations in your conjecture. I suspect there should be a proof of your conjecture using Pachner's theorem, but I haven't given it much thought.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very useful connection that we were not aware about!

Comment: Near the bottom, you write: "Now, because all the polytopes involved have vertices in $S$, the only triangulations involved are the ones with vertices in $S$." 
This seems to be unclear for $d\geq 3$, as then there are polytopes which cannot be triangulated without extra vertices. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron
Could you clarify, perhaps?

Comment: I finally found the result in the literature, so I updated my answer accordingly. I guess my previous idea was a bit of wishful thinking. I haven't been able to turn it into a rigorous proof.

Comment: Thanks for digging up these references, they are very useful!  
Regarding a possible connection with Pachner's Theorem, it does not seem likely. Indeed, in this setting, of point configurations, two triangulations of the same set need not be connected in this way, see e.g. 
http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2000-13-03/S0894-0347-00-00330-1/home.html

Comment: I am familiar with that article, but notice that Pachner moves are more general than the flips considered there. What I'm having trouble with is lifting a relation in $K(S)$ to a relation in an appropriate simplicial complex. I can't find a way to do this canonically, though I can do it by ad hoc methods in any configuration I've tried by hand.

Comment: We checked out Thm 7.3 in the first paper you cite, and we don't see how it settles our conjecture. Thm 7.3 is about the $d+2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. They also have Thm 7.4, which looks more to the point, but it is about the case $d=2$ only.

Comment: That was a typo. The theorems are 7.4 in the first paper, and it deals with dimension 2; and theorem 4.5 in the second paper which deals with the higher values.

Comment: OK, thanks. We will have to check the latter in detail, as it wasn't published...